# MySQL: Convert String to Float/Decimal in german language

Tags: mysql, string, floating-point

In a MySQL-table I have a `VARCHAR`-column with different values, which may represent String-, Integer-, Float-, Whatever-Values. These Values are written as a language-specific String into the Database, this means a float-value of `123.45` may be written as a String like `"123,45"` in german language (using VB.Net...)

As I need average values of float-values wich are in the same group:
How can I cast such a string to a `FLOAT` within MySQL?
Simply `AVG(CONVERT(value, DECIMAL))` won't work (returns 99.00000), conversion to `FLOAT` is not possible.

Charset is `utf8`, Collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Sample table:

```
id | value  | group
1  | 122,45 | 1
2  |  66,34 | 1
3  | blabla | 2
4  | 109,21 | 1
5  | bababa | 2
```

Goal: somethig like `SELECT AVG(CONVERT(value, DECIMAL)) FROM table WHERE (group=1)` should result in `99.333333`, not `99`.

Any Ideas?

Christoph

PS.: I did not make that database-layout...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '.', ''), ',', '.'), 
    DECIMAL(10,2))) 
FROM `table`
WHERE `group`=1
```

Comment: this may fail in some situations: in german language a value of T1234.56` may be written `"1.234,56"`. The above would result in the string `"1.234.56"` which would be converted to `1`.

Comment: Your edited code may work and may not: what, if the point is a decimal-point?
I decided to change the database layout a little, now I have a column for numeric data (float, int and boolean will be saved in a `DECIMAL(30,10)`-column) and another column for other data (text, serialized data, binary data, whatever).
Works better and allowes to calculate with the values in the numeric column in MySQL directly (AVG/MIN/MAX f.e.)

Comment: @ChristophMühlmann: I agree with you, but your example used comma as decimal separator!!

Comment: You are right with this. 

But I thought it would be better to change the database-layout in a way I don't need to differ between numeric and non-numeric values in one column anymore. 

The main problem was the database-layout, which was not quite well.

Comment: @ChristophMühlmann: yes, you're right with this. You did the right thing :)

Answer (score 0):

The string function format(x,d,locale) should do exactly what you want. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format